# Connecting to MySQL Server on localhost through Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, boot2docker

So, I'm able to generally contact my localhost through Docker by running a container with `--add-host=localbox:192.168.59.3`. `ping localbox` works just fine. Problem is, I can't seem to be able to even get a response from MySQL Server. `mysql -h localbox`, which works fine from outside of the docker container, just gets me `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localbox' (111)` from within.

I've done `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

I've added `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` into /etc/my.cnf. None of this helps. What gives?

Context: I'm running all of this through boot2docker on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: It seems that localbox is not recognized as a valid host name. What does it happen if you use the IP address instead of localbox from within the container?

Comment: localbox is a valid hostname. Like I said, pinging localbox works fine.

Comment: Do you mean pinging it from within the container?

Comment: Yes. Everything I mention aside from running the container and modifying mysql server configs, I'm doing from within the container.

Comment: What do you get running `netstat`? Is MySQL listening?

Comment: Yes. Through `lsof -i 3306`, I see `localhost:mysql (LISTEN)` (on localhost)

Comment: What about `mysql -h localhost`? Does it work? Which command do you use to run MySQL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67525/discussion-between-eli-and-mark91).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, turns out this is homebrew's fault with a really questionable design decision. You start-up mysql-server in homebrew by running the recommended `launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`. But then, when examining this file, you'll find the bind-address is hardcoded!

```
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--bind-address=127.0.0.1</string>
    <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
  </array>
```

So, no matter what you do in any of your my.cnf files, it will always be bound to 127.0.0.1, and you'll never be able to query from a container. My fix is just editing this file directly not to provide a bind address so we can let /etc/my.cnf do it for us. Alternatively, though I wouldn't recommend it, you can just change the bind-address directly in this file.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the mac host's network to your docker container (running in boot2docker) with

```
--add-host=dh:10.0.2.2
```

as part of your docker run command or using

```
extra_hosts:
  - "dh:10.0.2.2"
```

in your docker-compose.yml file.

After this, connecting to mysql from a container with the client installed is as simple as (e.g.):

```
$ mysql -h dh -uroot -p1234
```

This solution does not require modifying the settings for your mariadb/mysql installation, even if it is bound to 127.0.0.0.

Comment: Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495905/accessing-host-machine-as-localhost-from-a-docker-container-thats-also-inside-a and https://forums.docker.com/t/access-host-not-vm-from-inside-container/11747/4 for guiding me to this answer.