# Accessing host machine as localhost from a Docker container that's also inside a boot2docker vm

Tags: docker, boot2docker

Suppose I have a server running on port 8000 on OSX. How can my Docker container access it via `localhost:8000`? I can't change the hostname too as the app in the container is not in my control.

I've read this previous discussion on using `--net="host"` for a container to access the host machine's network. However, I'm on OSX and Docker runs inside a VM so *localhost* from the Docker container with `--net="host"` goes to the VM and not my real machine.

Then I tried [port forwarding workaround](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/WORKAROUNDS.md) like so: `VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port8000,tcp,,8000,,8000";` to no avail.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Thanks to palimpestor's answer I figured it out:

**Instead of `--net="host"`, use `--add-host="localhost:10.0.2.2"`**

Indeed:

- 10.0.2.2 is the default gateway defined for the guest network interface in NAT mode ([reference](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#idp46608647496736)).
  Read: *it's your host, seen from boot2docker.*
- `--add-host...` is adding `localhost   10.0.2.2` in /etc/hosts ([reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings))

Note: you need to have set up a NAT adapter in your boot2docker VM VirtualBox settings (I did it through the GUI, don't know the CLI).

Comment: I am not sure whats happening but this worked for me, I was trying to access local mongo in my container.

Comment: For those using docker-compose.yml  the equivalent of --add-host is the configuration option [extra_hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts)

Comment: That seems to be _adding_ a line to `/etc/hosts` - it does not override the existing line: `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Answer (score 17):

Instead of running with `--net="host"`, try `--add-host="localhost:192.168.59.3"`, which is the boot2docker host IP.

Comment: just pinging 192.168.59.3 from inside the container don't seem to get a response

Comment: During boot2docker initialization, boot2docker sets up two network adapters, one using NAT and the other a "host-only" adapter.  The IP of the host on that host-only network is determined by virtualbox.  You can inspect it by running `ifconfig` on your host and looking at the `vboxnet0` interface.  By default it's 192.168.59.3, but you can change it in virtualbox's global settings at Preferences -> Network -> Host-only Networks.  I am  able to ping that IP both from within the boot2docker VM and from within a running docker container.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your intent, it is to: *Connect from a container to a host machine port*

As of 18.3, the docker team has us covered:

Us the alias `host.docker.internal`

> I WANT TO CONNECT FROM A CONTAINER TO A SERVICE ON THE HOST
>   The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name `host.docker.internal`, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Windows.
>
> The gateway is also reachable as `gateway.docker.internal`.
>
> https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/

Comment: The simplest solution of all