# Connect container to local database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-machine

I'm using docker to make redmine running on server and I create another container with postgresql and link to one another.

I'm new using docker but I want my redmine container connect to my localhost postgresql instead linking to my another container.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you use the Docker Engine on Linux, you could use the --net=host option, so your container is capable of interacting with the network stack of your host machine.

See: https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/articles/networking/#how-docker-networks-a-container

but since you tagged this with 'docker-machine' I assume you want to run this on Windows or OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the IP of the docker host from within your container, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/6309) (`ip addr show eth0`).

Or you can add [localhost using the guest network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33621207/6309) (if you are using a VM)

```
--add-host="localhost:10.0.2.2"
```