# How to connect to service in the host machine from inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, containers

I have a docker daemon started in the host machine listen to some ip address and port, say 10.10.10.10, and port 1234, then I start a container by invoking

```
sudo docker -H 10.10.10.10:1234 centos /bin/bash
```

Meanwhile, I have a web service runnig on the host machine, running on the port 8080. Then from inside the container, I cannot connect to this server. I tried

```
curl http://10.10.10.10:8080
```

but got an error message:

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

But I can access the server in other machines, like http://10.10.10.11:8080
It seems that docker container cannot access the service in its own host machine? Is there anyway to fix this? Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556301/connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-docker/27564532#27564532

Answer (score 7):

That was discussed in [issue 1143](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1143) and there [might be one day a `--link-host` option](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11247).

In the meantime, the blog post "[Accessing the Docker Host Server Within a Container](http://blog.michaelhamrah.com/2014/06/accessing-the-docker-host-server-within-a-container/)" lists a few option:

- The Gateway Approach: `netstat -nr | grep '^0\.0\.0\.0' | awk '{print $2}'`
- The IP Approach: boot2docker ip address is 192.168.59.103.

> Although there’s no way to introspect the host’s ip address (AFAIK) you can pass this in via an environment variable:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$  docker run -i -t -e DOCKER_HOST=192.168.59.103 ubuntu /bin/bash
root@07561b0607f4:/# env
HOSTNAME=07561b0607f4
DOCKER_HOST=192.168.59.103
```

You have other options in "[Network Configuration](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/)", with the virtual interface named `docker0` on the host machine.

Answer (score 2):

Eight years after the question was posted there is a well supported solution.

From the [Docker official doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-host):

```bash
echo "hello from host!" > ./hello
python3 -m http.server 8000
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
docker run \
  --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway \
  curlimages/curl -s host.docker.internal:8000/hello
hello from host!
```

An [answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70725881/what-is-the-equivalent-of-add-host-host-docker-internalhost-gateway-in-a-comp) shows how to accomplish the same thing in Docker Compose instead.