# How to use host's network inside Airflow built on Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, localhost, airflow

I want to migrate from old Airflow that is installed locally to a new one. I am trying to run new Airflow trough Docker and Docker Compose. I am using official [docker-compose.yml](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.3/docker-compose.yaml). The problem that I have is that I can't send email using python smtplib and I am confident that the problem is in network settings of my container. I have tried everything from [swiss_knights's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70725881/what-is-the-equivalent-of-add-host-host-docker-internalhost-gateway-in-a-comp), but I could not make it work. When I run
`docker compose up` I get infinite loop of
`.` prints from services in which I put `network_mode: "host"`.

I would prefere to use hots's network so my codebase migration can be seamless (`localhost` part of my .py files won't need editing). How should I edit my .yml file?

Linux CentOS 7, Docker 24.0.5 and Docker Compose v2.20.2

I tried:

- adding `network_mode: "host"` in each service
- adding

```
network_mode: bridge
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

to each service

- created custom network as per [swiss_knights's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70725881/what-is-the-equivalent-of-add-host-host-docker-internalhost-gateway-in-a-comp)