# Not dockerized nginx load balancing to gitlab dockerized

Tags: nginx, docker, mariadb

I have installed iRedMail on my server which has installed **nginx**.
I have installed docker then gitlab in a docker container.

Is it possible to load balance from the nginx outside docker to the gitlab into the docker container ? I don't know the Ip neither the port.

I also need to use the MariaDB local container with the Gitlab docker container.

Comment: you can get your container's ip address from host by running `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <Container ID>`.

Comment: Not a good solution, it mean every reboot I need to update the nginx.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to load balance from the nginx outside docker to the gitlab into the docker container ?

You can make automatic updated `nginx.conf` by using [docker-gen](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen)

Firstly, install `docker-gen` on your host by following [doc](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen#host-install)

Then, you should make a `docker-gen` template to generate your `nginx` config file.

Assume your gitlab container named `gitlab`, and we bind it to a domain `gitlab.domain.com`, then we have this template

```
{{ range $name, $containers := groupBy $ "Name" }}
{{ $target_name := "gitlab"}}
{{ if $name==$target_name}}
upstream {{ $name }} {

{{ range $index, $value := $containers }}
    {{ with $address := index $value.Addresses 0 }}
    server {{ $address.IP }}:{{ $address.Port }};
    {{ end }}
{{ end }}

}
{{ end }}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gitlab.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://{{ $name }};
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
{{ end }}
```

Last, we run `docker-gen` to automatic generate target nginx config file with

`docker-gen -watch -only-exposed -notify "nginx -s reload" nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab.conf`

---

> I also need to use the MariaDB local container with the Gitlab docker container.

you can expose host ip to your docker container's host file, here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27564532/2382404) to do this.