# Docker-compose linking containers

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup a CD/CI build environment with docker compose.
I have a jenkins container, a sonar container and an archiva container. The problem is, my jenkins cannot connect to sonar and archiva.

I tried linking multiple containers together or joining them in the same network, but still no success.

In jenkins, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8081 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

This is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  data-jenkins:
    driver: 'local'
  data-postgres:
    driver: 'local'
  data-sonarqube-conf: 
    driver: 'local'
  data-sonarqube-data: 
    driver: 'local'
  data-archiva:
    driver: 'local'

services:
  jenkins:
    image: 'jenkins'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - 'data-jenkins:/var/jenkins_home'
    links:
      - 'sonarqube:sonarqube'
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:9.6.1'
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - 'data-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
  sonarqube:
    image: 'sonarqube'
    depends_on:
      - 'postgres'
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    links:
      - 'postgres:postgres'
    environment:
      - 'SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/'
      - 'SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=postgres'
      - 'SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=postgres'
    volumes:
      - 'data-sonarqube-data:/var/lib/sonarqube/data'
      - 'data-sonarqube-conf:/var/lib/sonarqube/conf'
  archiva:
    image: 'xetusoss/archiva'
    ports:
      - '8081:8080'
    volumes:
      - 'data-archiva:/var/archiva'
    environment:
      - 'SSL_ENABLED=false'
```

It seems the Jenkins container is living in a seperate environment. Does anyone how can i join all the environments together? Been struggling with this problem for almost a week now

Comment: yes, they are living in different environments, so to speak. to help you understand what is going on, get into the jenkins container (`docker exit -it [CONTAINER_ID] bash`) after you fire them all up, and then `ping archiva`. you were attempting connect to localhost, which won't work. it may or may not work to `ping archiva` (since you're not linking it to the jenkins container), but you can mess with it. it looks like you're currently linking to sonarqube, so i'd expect that ping to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference your sonarqube container from Jenkins use sonarqube:9000 docker will translate your service name *sonarqube* to the ip of that container.

I would also recommend using different networks rather than links to connect your containers.

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer so other users can reference it too.

Comment: @ssc327 Why is it better to use different networks rather than links? I would love more detail on this

Comment: @Loren I believe that links are deprecated. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294305/docker-compose-difference-between-network-and-link

Answer (score 0):

This is because the ping  is going to sonarqube.