# Can not connect PostgreSQL database from docker to python

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I am trying to use Postgresql with python. I have used the following docker compose the file.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin_123
      POSTGRES_USER: admin

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

With the following code, I am trying to connect with the database.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database = "db_test",
    user ="admin",
    password = "admin_123",
    host = "db"
)
```

But I am getting this error.

> OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address:
>   nodename nor servname provided, or not known

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker-compose: difference between network and link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294305/docker-compose-difference-between-network-and-link)

Comment: how ? would you please explain ? I read that but not getting it

Comment: Where is your Python code running; on the host or in a container?  If in a container, how did you start it?

Comment: I am working with Jupyter there

Comment: Sorry, this link is probably irrelevant here. I thought you are trying to access `db` inside `adminer`, is it correct?

Comment: I am trying to access DB with python

Comment: @TheTechGuy Are you trying to connect to the database from your host machine?

Comment: yes, the same machine where the docker is running , I just need to insert data to the database. The database is running in Docker. and I have a Jupyter notebook with that I am trying to connect. While I am trying to connect i got the mentioned error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to expose the BD port in the docker compose like this :

```
db:
image: postgres
restart: always
environment:
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin_123
  POSTGRES_USER: admin
ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

And then connect with **localhost:5432**

Answer (score 1):

Another possible scenario,

Check if ports have been used or not by other docker container.
Use command:

```
$ docker container ls --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}" -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my docker-compose.yml

$ cat docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1' # specify docker-compose version
services:
  dockerpgdb:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: Password
      POSTGRES_DB: dockerpgdb
      POSTGRES_USER: abcUser
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql%
```

Now in PgAdmin4 you can setup a new server as below to test the connection:

```
host: localhost
port: 5432
maintenance database: postgres
username: abcUser
password: Password
```