# Docker, Springboot and Mysql : com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker, jdbc

I try to run a Springboot app with mysql connection on Docker. Without docker, it works well. But when I try to deploy on a container, I have `com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure`.
I use this docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
   container_name: nginx
   image: nginx:latest
   restart: always
   ports:
   - 80:80
   - 443:443
   volumes:
   - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
   depends_on:
   - spring-boot-app


  mysql:
   container_name: mysql
   image: mysql:latest
   environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpass"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: "db"
    MYSQL_USER: "user"
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pass"
   ports:
   - "1306:3306"
   volumes:
   - ./data/:/var/lib/mysql
   networks: 
   - mysql-db
   restart: always

  spring-boot-app:
    container_name: spring-boot-app
    image: spring-boot-app
    build:
      context: ./spring-boot-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks: 
      - mysql-db
    restart: always

networks: 
  mysql-db:
      driver: bridge
```

Here is the Dockerfile for springboot app:

```
FROM openjdk:11
COPY target/spring-boot-app.jar /spring-boot-app/spring-boot-app.jar
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod","/spring-boot-app/spring-boot-app.jar" ]
```

And finally, here is application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql:1306/db
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = pass

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

server.port=8080
```

I don't think this is a port problem because i tried to set mysql to default port (3306), and it still doesn't work.

If it can help, here is `docker ps` :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                      NAMES
08ea16361c61        nginx:latest        "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   1 second ago        Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   nginx
52ef8d5c2127        spring-boot-app     "java -jar -Dspring.…"   3 seconds ago       Up 1 second             0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                     spring-boot-app
7bbcdc1fae3c        mysql:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds            33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1306->3306/tcp          mysql
```

Edit : full stacktrace :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Documents/SpringBoot$ docker-compose up
Creating network "springboot_mysql-db" with driver "bridge"
Creating mysql ... done
Creating spring-boot-app ... done
Attaching to mysql, spring-boot-app
mysql              | 2019-05-27T21:50:19.645920Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
mysql              | 2019-05-27T21:50:19.645986Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 1
mysql              | 2019-05-27T21:50:20.451523Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting crash recovery...
mysql              | 2019-05-27T21:50:20.466040Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] Crash recovery finished.
mysql              | 2019-05-27T21:50:20.544487Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql              | 2019-05-27T21:50:20.551894Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql              | 2019-05-27T21:50:20.584210Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.16'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysql              | 2019-05-27T21:50:20.682338Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
spring-boot-app    | 
spring-boot-app    |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
spring-boot-app    |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
spring-boot-app    | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
spring-boot-app    |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
spring-boot-app    |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
spring-boot-app    |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
spring-boot-app    |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)
spring-boot-app    | 
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:22.884  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.jv.demo.DemoApplication              : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on c69469fd7461 with PID 1 (/spring-boot-app/spring-boot-app.jar started by root in /)
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:22.903  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.jv.demo.DemoApplication              : The following profiles are active: prod
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:25.152  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:25.378  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 205ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:26.313  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e43b97d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:27.043  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:27.195  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:27.196  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:27.472  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:27.472  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4316 ms
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:27.928  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:29.226 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
spring-boot-app    | 
spring-boot-app    | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
spring-boot-app    | 
spring-boot-app    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:73) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:142) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:113) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d1a7bec.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$5(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d1a7bec$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cb57d9da.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d1a7bec.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.jv.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[spring-boot-app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[spring-boot-app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
spring-boot-app    |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[spring-boot-app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
spring-boot-app    | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
spring-boot-app    | 
spring-boot-app    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    ... 84 common frames omitted
spring-boot-app    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
spring-boot-app    |    ... 87 common frames omitted
spring-boot-app    | 
spring-boot-app    | 2019-05-27 21:50:29.234  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
spring-boot-app    | 
spring-boot-app    | org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace

Comment: When i run mysql alone with the docker compose, it works well. The problem come from springboot i guess

Comment: The important part is _"java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"_. You are trying to connect to a host:port combination that isn't open. This is technically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Comment: IIRC when using docker-compose, you need to use the original port between images and not the mapped port, so you would need to use port 3306, not port 1306.

Comment: really? but i already have another mysql instance which run on 3306, but which is not in a container. So it gave me this error: proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use

Comment: No, in your `application.properties` I think (not 100% sure), you should use port 3306, not 1306.

Comment: Damn thank you it works ! If i understand well, 1306:3306 just expose the port 1306 and redirect on 3306? So if i don't want db port to be exposed, just remove this line will be ok?

Comment: 1306 is the port exposed **outside** of docker that redirects to port 3306 of the image, but inside docker, the images communicate using their original ports.

Comment: ok thanks, you can post it as answer if you wants

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your Spring Boot application is also launched in a docker image, you can't used the port exposed by docker, but instead you need to use the original port of the image.

In `application.properties` you need to use:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/db
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a difference between `networks` and `links`. use links like the one below

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build: . 
        links: 
            - "db:database"
    db:
        image: postgres
```

this switch will add ID and IP address of one docker container in another on. in this way they can connect to each other. for more info check following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294305/docker-compose-difference-between-network-and-link).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but on the link you gives to me, the answer said that:
Links have been replaced by networks. Docker describes them as a legacy feature that you should avoid using. You can safely remove the link and the two containers will be able to refer to each other by their service name (or container_name).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. check this instead, shouldn't your nginx be in the same network as the others? I assume Nginx would act as gateway, if this is what you want it should be able to see api at least.