# docker container connect local postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I run python container, I want to connect localhost postegresql. And I try some method. But not work. Please talk me. How can I do ? Thanks.

I have run postegresql on port 5432, create datatbase and grant user.

run docker comand

```
docker run --name=python3 -v ${pwd}:/code -w /code python
```

python code

```
import psycopg2

def main():
    #Define our connection string
    conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='testDB' user='test' password='test'"

    # print the connection string we will use to connect
    print ("Connecting to database\n    ->{}".format(conn_string))

    # get a connection, if a connect cannot be made an exception will be raised here
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

    # conn.cursor will return a cursor object, you can use this cursor to perform queries
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print ("Connected!\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

error message

> Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>               TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>       could not connect to server: Connection refused
>               Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>               TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your host OS and your docker version.
I assume here your database is not running in a container itself, but rather on the host itself (localhost).

For instance, as mentioned in "[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541681/6309)", with Docker for Mac v 17.06 and above (June 2017), you can connect to the special Mac-only DNS name `docker.for.mac.localhost` which will resolve to the internal IP address used by the host.

On Linux directly, you would use the host mode, with an image having `ifconfig` installed:

```
docker run --network="host" -id <Docker image ID>
```

Comment: Hi, I try `docker run --name=python3 -v ${pwd}:/code -w /code --network="host" python`, but not work. My OS is Wiindows 10. database is run on local machine. not container. Thanks. Will I still need to do anything?

Comment: @frank For Windows, you can use the bridge network, and pass the Hyper-V IP address: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41077351/6309

Comment: @frank Note: the other answer is if you are running postgreSQL inside its own container, which was not your question.

Comment: @frank, it will be useful to edit your question pointing out that Postgres is running on a virtual machine on top of Windows. It is not running on localhost as you said first

Answer (score 1):

Reading that you're on Windows 10 and running postgresql on the host, I advise you to run postgresql in a container. It makes this way easier.

To connect the python container to the postgres container you'll need a docker network though. Let's call it postgres_backend.

`docker network create postgres_backend`

You can create the postgresql container with the following command. Just change the /path/to/store/data to a local directory in which you'd like to store the postgres data:

```
docker run --name postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=test \
  -d --restart always \
  -v /path/to/store/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  --net postgres_backend \
  postgres:9.6
```

Now your postresql container should be up and running :)

To connect your python container to it, you'll have to add a `--net postgres_backend` to your docker run command and change the host in your script to "postgres" (it's the name we gave the postgres container with `--name`).

If the python container can't find the host "postgres", try it with the IP shown when entering the command `docker exec -ti postgres ip addr show`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your solution. I try this method and It works, but I just want to connect local database, Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this can be of more help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556301/how-to-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-docker

Answer (score 0):

to fix this bug:

First, it is normal that it does not work, because postgresql does not run in the same container as the application so the host localhost: 5432 does not exist.
to fix it : 
on the properties file isntead localhost:5432 use your IPadresse like IP:5432 and in the pg_hba.conf add this 
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5